# Angular ng src not working in Visual Studio Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have a ng-src problem in Cordova Visual Studio, where it worked prior in prior Cordova CLI version (i tried going back to 5, etc but it did not work).

I also have an image in its default:

```
<img src="example.jpg" />
```

and an angular image:

```
<img ng-src="example.jpg" />
```

side by side and the default is working but not the angular version.

I also tried $sceDelegateProvider fix but that didnt work either.

I am attaching my index.html code and screenshot of the 2 images (one is working).

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
               <html>
                   <head>
                       <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

                    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
                    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
                    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
                    <title>TEST</title>
                </head>
               <body ng-app="">
                <h2>Device is Ready</h2>

                <div ng-init="myVar = 'pic_angular.jpg'">
                    <h1>Angular ng-src</h1>
                    <img ng-src="{{myVar}}" alt="this is where image should display">
                    <h1>img src</h1>
                    <img src="pic_angular.jpg" />
                </div>

                <div ng-app="">
                    <p>My expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
               </body>
               </html>
```

Why is the ng-src not working? Is it cordova version issue? Visual Studio issue? Coding issue?

[image]

Comment: Which cordova platform? Do you get any errors on the console?  Install the console plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console in cordova to see these errors)

Comment: UPDATE: on Windows/local the images dont show up. But in ios and Android they do. Is there something overwriting the styles for Windows devices?

Comment: I haven't done much with windows and Angular, but I do know that if you are building a "Windows Store App", you have to do some ceremony with MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction and certain functions that it considers "unsafe" (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792383/how-do-you-get-angular-js-to-work-in-a-windows-8-store-app).  Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32454292/cordova-windows-8-1-on-visual-studio-2015-external-image-loading-to-img-tag?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows platform using angular to set the img-src, some prefix will be automatically added for safety reason. Please see "Fix URL Prefixes" Section of [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msdn_answers/2015/02/10/running-cordova-apps-on-windows-and-windows-phone-8-1-using-ionic-angularjs-and-other-frameworks/).Thus the img won't load correctly.

To fix this issue add the following codes to your index.js file:

```
//"myApp" is the your module
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|ms-appx|ms-appx-web|x-wmapp0):|data:image\//);
}]);
```

Notes: different from the blog said, I added "ms-appx-web" to the string pattern.

Comment: Wow. That worked. Thank you for the blog page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Angular evaluates the expression in ng-src, so it is probably looking for a variable named example.jpg rather than treats it as an url.

If you use this, it should work:

```
<img ng-src="imgUrl">
```

And in your code assign the actual URL to the imgUrl variable.

Comment: I am assigning ng-src="{{myVar}}" to the angular img. It shows up on ios and Android Ripple simulator but not for any Windows emulators.